# Can i ask about code suggestions at SO?

Tags: support, scope

I want to know ways to improve some code, could i ask that at SO?
For example asking something like this at SO is valid:

> "I've got some code in Angular.js, i've followed John Papa's style
>   guide, is there a way to improve what i've done?, i want to know if
>   should declare the empty arrays or not? also the functions that
>   basically do the same should be improved in a way to DRY?"

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It should instead be asked at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). From the [Code Review Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.